# how can i set the start date ,time and end date,time in dateandtime picker in iphone?

Tags: ios, iphone, datetimepicker

How to set start date,time and end date,time in date and time picker,if we select any  date need to enable only start time and end time for example start time 09:00am to 05:00 pm.

Answer (score 2):

Use minimumDate and maximumDate properties

```
NSDateComponents* dc = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[dc setYear:2011];
...
NSCalendar* c = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDate* date = [c dateFromComponents:dc];
dp.minimumDate = date;
....
datePicker.maximumDate = d;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your view you create UIDatePicker from story board. if select any date that date will display on textField like this:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
//NSDate *date = [[NSDate alloc]init];
NSDate *date = [sender date];
NSString *formattedDateStringTime = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
[self setSelectedDate:formattedDateStringTime];
NSLog(@"value: %@",formattedDateStringTime);
[formatter release];

//if (currentTextField.tag==101) {
currentTextField.text=formattedDateStringTime;
```

try this current date will display on textfield and like this you need to get end time. finally give text for text filed is:

```
currentTextField.text=[NSString StringWithFormat:"%@ to %@",formattedDateStringTime,formattedDateEndTime];
```

try this I think you can get answer.